# Angular/Javascript - Custom User Scripts (Eval)

Tags: javascript, angular, eval

Hi we are building a web app platform where users can make their own smart forms using drag and drop features. We are looking for a way for admin users to create their own custom scripts to run some logic using pre-defined functions for the app. Currently the solution we have come up is using eval().

Knowing Eval is 'evil' we have implemented a function to check if the script is safe before it is executed. Essentially it breaks up the code into tokens and then runs those tokens against a blacklist. Stuff like new, eval, window, require, fetch,browser will show an error. Also the function is executed via a angular service so we try to limit what is injected.

Below is the basic high-level code. We have custom async functions so the solution needs to handle this.

My question is there a better(ie faster) and safer way to run custom scripts?

```
async runScript(script,callback) {
 var updateForm=(id,value)=>{
   return this.updateForm(id,value);
 }
 var getForm=(id)=>{
   return this.getForm(id);
 }
 if (this.checkScriptSafe(script)) {       
       try {
          return eval("(async () => {" + script + "})()"); 
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
                alert(e.message);
            } else {
              console.log('Error',e);
              alert("Error in script");
            }
        }
  } else { 
    alert("Script not safe")
   }
}
```

Example script:

```
"var value = 1 +4; await updateForm("11",value);alert("Success!");"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) would be a better approach. Function constructor creates a new function that will execute in the global scope. Your eval script (because of the arrow function) will run in the same context as your `runScript` method. They would access/modify your internals, or override your class methods. They can even override the `runScript` method itself and remove the `checkScriptSafe` check.

Using the function constructor is similar to typing in the dev tools console. If your application is not vulnerable to the dev tools console, then you wouldn't have any issues using the function constructor.

Here is an example:

```js
const script = `
  var value = 1 +4;\n
  await updateForm("11",value);\n
  alert("Success!");
`;

// we have to get a handle of the async function constructor
// in order to create an async function
const dummyFunction = async function() {}
const AsyncFunction = dummyFunction.constructor;

// create an async function which will run in the global scope
// the function will have an `updateForm` parameter
const userFunction = new AsyncFunction('updateForm', script);

// now userFunction is equavalent of:
// const userFunction = async function(updateForm) {
//   var value = 1 +4;
//   await updateForm("11",value);
//   alert("Success!");
// }

// bind the current context 'this' to update form and pass it
// to user's function as parameter. The user's function
// will be able to execute it.
userFunction(this.updateForm.bind(this));
```

I'm not an expert in browser internals. But I assume tokenizing and interpreting the function on your own would be much slower than the Function constructor method. Even if you do everything in the most efficient way, you would still be in the JavaScript domain; v8 (or any other JS engine) would perform the actual interpretation after you. Why not directly give the script to the JS engine then? If the same custom script is going to run frequently, then with the right design, v8 will optimize the custom functions by [compiling them into machine code](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/06/v8-sparkplug-compiler/). This wouldn't be the case with `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and feedback. I did look at the Function constructor however can you pass your custom functions so it can be accessed via the custom script? eg as in the example updateForm. Also I assume making tokenising the code and then making our own custom interpretor will be alot slower than Function or Eval?

Comment: Hi @KaTech, I have updated the answer and added an example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and providing the example. It really helps as I couldn't find much on the topic. Your comment 'Why not directly give the script to the JS engine then' I assuming this is the function solution you suggested, correct? Or is it something else?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I was suggesting the function solution. The v8 will tokenize and interpret the given string for you. If you use a custom `tokenizeAndInterpret` function, v8 would have to interpret both your custom function and its output. By getting out of v8's way altogether (by not using a custom tokenizer etc. and using the Function constructor instead) we gain speed and efficiency.

Comment: Awesome that makes alot of sense, thanks for explaining! One question i did try your code in stackblitz but get a type script error (Function no construct signature). Any ideas why? If not all good will do a seperate post. Link below. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdhhw9?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Hi @KaTech, I managed to get it working but I had to drop `await` support in custom user scripts. Users will have to use the chaining method (`then`, `catch`, and `finally`) in their scripts if they are working with promises. Accessing the [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) constructor was not possible with that dummy function method. Here is the stackblitz fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfjbrs?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much for doing this, you're a legend! :)

Comment: Actually got it working with const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor; https://angular-uhvyeu.stackblitz.io Thanks again.